# I want to check the user name against a value and nested query

Tags: sql, oracle

In the below code what i am trying to do is limit results by either the wkf.email_address of the requester or the wkf.email_address of the buyer

However i get BUYER_EMAIL not a a valid identifier.

fairly new to sql so i am sure this is incorrect syntax.

It works on the requester email only ie

```
AND    WKF.EMAIL_ADDRESS = :xdo_user_name
```

instead of

```
AND    WKF.EMAIL_ADDRESS = :xdo_user_name OR BUYER_EMAIL  = :xdo_user_name
```

---

This is my code

```
      SELECT DISTINCT APA.INVOICE_NUM,
                  APA.INVOICE_AMOUNT,
                  TO_CHAR (APA.INVOICE_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') INVOICE_DATE,
                  SUP.VENDOR_NAME,
                  SSV.VENDOR_SITE_CODE,
                  POH.DOCUMENT_NUM PO_NUMBER,
                  POH.COMMENTS,
                  WKF.EMAIL_ADDRESS AS REQUESTOR_EMAIL,
                  WKF.FULL_NAME AS REQUESTOR_NAME,
                  (SELECT WKF.EMAIL_ADDRESS
                     FROM PER_WORKFORCE_X WKF, PO_HEADERS_INTERFACE POH
                    WHERE     POH.PO_HEADER_ID = PLO.PO_HEADER_ID
                          AND POH.AGENT_NAME = WKF.FULL_NAME)
                     AS BUYER_EMAIL
    --

    FROM AP_INVOICE_LINES_ALL AIL,
         AP_INVOICES_ALL APA,
         POZ_SUPPLIERS_V SUP,
         POZ_SUPPLIER_SITES_V SSV                                           --
                                 ,
         PO_HEADERS_INTERFACE POH,
         PO_LINES_ALL PLO,
         PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL PLL,
         PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL PDA                                           --
                                 ,
         AP_HOLDS_ALL HOLDS,
         PER_WORKFORCE_X WKF
   WHERE        APA.INVOICE_ID = AIL.INVOICE_ID
            AND SUP.VENDOR_ID = SSV.VENDOR_ID
            AND APA.VENDOR_SITE_ID = SSV.VENDOR_SITE_ID
            AND POH.PO_HEADER_ID = PLO.PO_HEADER_ID
            AND PLO.PO_LINE_ID = PLL.PO_LINE_ID
            AND PLL.LINE_LOCATION_ID = PDA.LINE_LOCATION_ID
            AND PDA.DELIVER_TO_PERSON_ID = WKF.PERSON_ID
            --

            AND APA.INVOICE_ID = HOLDS.INVOICE_ID
            AND PLL.LINE_LOCATION_ID = HOLDS.LINE_LOCATION_ID(+)
            AND PDA.DELIVER_TO_PERSON_ID = WKF.PERSON_ID
            --

            AND PDA.PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID = AIL.PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID
            AND POH.DOCUMENT_NUM NOT LIKE ('CP%')
            AND SSV.VENDOR_SITE_CODE LIKE ('%B')
            AND WKF.EMAIL_ADDRESS = :xdo_user_name
         OR BUYER_EMAIL = :xdo_user_name
ORDER BY WKF.FULL_NAME, POH.DOCUMENT_NUM, APA.INVOICE_NUM
```

Expected result is that it either shows the requester their own PO's or shows the Buyer all the ones where they are the Buyer (Multiple requesters)

Comment: the OR must be linked only to the AND statement

Comment: also this still gives the BUYER_EMAIL invalid indentifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` Should be enclosed into parenthesis:

```
AND (   WKF.EMAIL_ADDRESS = :xdo_user_name OR BUYER_EMAIL  = :xdo_user_name)
```

**[EDIT]**

Right; BUYER_EMAIL. It is invalid, indeed, in this context. You can't reference it that way. A simple option is to use current query as an inline view, and select data from it if the :XDO_USER_NAME condition is met.

```
  SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                 APA.INVOICE_NUM,
                 APA.INVOICE_AMOUNT,
                 TO_CHAR (APA.INVOICE_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') INVOICE_DATE,
                 SUP.VENDOR_NAME,
                 SSV.VENDOR_SITE_CODE,
                 POH.DOCUMENT_NUM PO_NUMBER,
                 POH.COMMENTS,
                 WKF.EMAIL_ADDRESS AS REQUESTOR_EMAIL,
                 WKF.FULL_NAME AS REQUESTOR_NAME,
                 (SELECT WKF.EMAIL_ADDRESS
                    FROM PER_WORKFORCE_X WKF, PO_HEADERS_INTERFACE POH
                   WHERE     POH.PO_HEADER_ID = PLO.PO_HEADER_ID
                         AND POH.AGENT_NAME = WKF.FULL_NAME)
                    AS BUYER_EMAIL
            --
            FROM AP_INVOICE_LINES_ALL AIL,
                 AP_INVOICES_ALL APA,
                 POZ_SUPPLIERS_V SUP,
                 POZ_SUPPLIER_SITES_V SSV,
                 PO_HEADERS_INTERFACE POH,
                 PO_LINES_ALL PLO,
                 PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL PLL,
                 PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL PDA,
                 AP_HOLDS_ALL HOLDS,
                 PER_WORKFORCE_X WKF
           WHERE     APA.INVOICE_ID = AIL.INVOICE_ID
                 AND SUP.VENDOR_ID = SSV.VENDOR_ID
                 AND APA.VENDOR_SITE_ID = SSV.VENDOR_SITE_ID
                 AND POH.PO_HEADER_ID = PLO.PO_HEADER_ID
                 AND PLO.PO_LINE_ID = PLL.PO_LINE_ID
                 AND PLL.LINE_LOCATION_ID = PDA.LINE_LOCATION_ID
                 AND PDA.DELIVER_TO_PERSON_ID = WKF.PERSON_ID
                 --

                 AND APA.INVOICE_ID = HOLDS.INVOICE_ID
                 AND PLL.LINE_LOCATION_ID = HOLDS.LINE_LOCATION_ID(+)
                 AND PDA.DELIVER_TO_PERSON_ID = WKF.PERSON_ID
                 --

                 AND PDA.PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID = AIL.PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID
                 AND POH.DOCUMENT_NUM NOT LIKE ('CP%')
                 AND SSV.VENDOR_SITE_CODE LIKE ('%B'))
   WHERE     1 = 1
         AND (   REQUESTOR_EMAIL = :xdo_user_name
              OR BUYER_EMAIL = :xdo_user_name)
ORDER BY REQUESTOR_NAME, PO_NUMBER, INVOICE_NUM
```

Comment: still get the BUYER_EMAIL not a valid identifier result

Comment: True. I edited my message and added some more info. Have a look, please.